# How to know if the adjective corresponding to a noun bears an umlaut?

Tags: adjective, noun, inflection, umlaut

Among the adjectives derived from nouns there some which do not bear *Umlaut*:

> die Kugel - kugelig, der Monat - monatlich, usw.

But sometimes they do bear *Umlaut*:

> das Jahr - jährlich, die Woche - wöchentlich, die Minute - minütlich, usw.

Some time ago I expected that *monthly* could be *mönatlich* but I was wrong. 
Is there a rule that helps by knowing when does the adjective bear *Umlaut*?

Comment: There may be explanations for each and every case, I think the origin of the words plays a role, the first vowel shift and language change, e.g. which variant (lower vs high German) eventually found its way into our high German standard. But to a learner EM1's answer will most likely be the ultimate one.

Comment: @bouscher *-wöchig* is also valid. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_woechig

Comment: @Em1 Ja schon, aber nur als Suffix, alle anderen Beispiele sind Vollworte. Der Viertelgeviertstrich dient ja hier nur als Worttrenner und nicht als Bindestrich.

Comment: @Em1 genau, ich habe eigentlich das Adjektiv als Suffix gedacht: *2-wöchiger Kurs*, usw. Aber es ist besser mit *wöchentlich*.

Comment: Die Suffixe haben unterschiedliche Bedeutung: Ein _zweiwöchiger Kurs_ dauert zwei Wochen, ein _zweiwöchentlicher Kurs_ findet nur jede zweite Woche statt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a look at canoo.net will help you. You not only find a lot of examples and 'rules' for noun to adjective but also for all other possibilities.

In German: [Nomen zu Adjektiv: Suffigierung](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/N-To-A/Suffig.html?MenuId=WordFormationRules11110)
In English: [Noun to adjective: Suffixation](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/N-To-A/Suffig.html?lang=en)

Well, only issue is that you'll learn that the suffix *-ig* can lead to an umlaut but not necessarily.
Furthermore, you'll see that there are thousands of combinations. Have fun with burning them into your mind.